# bind data on dropdownlist

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm trying run this code

```
  private void LoadProdName()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT productName
                             FROM Products3
                            WHERE productType = @Type",con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type",ddlProducts.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ddlProdName.DataSource = dt;
        ddlProdName.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```

my selectedIndesChange codes:

```
   protected void ddlProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadProdName();
    }
```

which uses the value of my first dropdownlist.My problem is whenever I select a ProductType on my dropdownlist it will fill my second DDL with the select query but I am not getting any data at all from my second dropdownlist.

Now I'm getting some progress.
This is what I get now:
[image]

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: and where exactly is con coming from?

Comment: @dinotom `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = localhost\SqlEXPRESS;
                                                    Initial Catalog = MejOnlineManagementDB00;
                                                     Integrated Security=True;");`

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler I can't get any data from my ddlProductName.

Comment: @rai nalasa...well unless con is global, that method shouldn't work

Comment: Did you mean you cannot get data to display data in your ddlProdName? Are you sure your "dt" has some value?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler Yes

Comment: Great, you will need to provide DisplayMember property so that the combobox knows which info to display from the object.

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler combo box?I think I'm not using any combo box here.Or am I using one?

Comment: well in winforms, they both are very similar. What is the type of your "ddlProdName"?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler type?like data type?It is varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cascade drowdownlist you must do a postback in your dropdownlist event "OnSelectedIndexChanged" or use an AJAX call to your method

try this guide: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Cascading-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx

try this code after your query

```
        ddlProdName.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        ddlProdName.DataTextField = "productName";

        ddlProdName.DataValueField = "productName"; //or productId

        ddlProdName.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will want to do:

```
ddlProdName.DataTextField = "productName"; //this is the name of column that's in your datatable.
ddlProdName.DataValueField = "productName";
```

If you are specifying anything other than collection of simple data type as the data source, you will need to specify the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` (in winforms) and `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` (in webforms, from Sergio's answer) property of the combobox so that it knows which property to display and which should be used as value.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn prodName = new DataColumn("Products");
        dt.Columns.Add(prodName);
        dt.Rows.Add("a");
        dt.Rows.Add("b");
        dt.Rows.Add("c");

        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Products";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Products";
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Updated my question.I think this is for windows form?not asp right?

Comment: I did this sample in WinForm, but the combo box control should behave fundamentally the same. Could you try the last bit from my answer and see if that helps?

Comment: @NoSaidCompliler I can't use DisplayMember on Asp.

Comment: Ok.. could you tell me the type of your ddlProdName (just hover your mouse over it). Does it have a property called datamember?

Comment: As SergioRamirez mentioned in his answer, the equivalent property you need to set could be DataTextField. Could you try that? Updated the statement in my answer..

Comment: I did try it.Sorry I replied late.Slow Internet connection problem a while ago